# Creating an equivalent DFA for this NFA

Tags: automata

I have an **NFA** and I want to make an equivalent version of it as a **DFA**. What will the *final DFA* diagram look like?

[This is the NFA I want to find an equivalent DFA for.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/508fS.png)

**My attempt:**

I've constructed a transition table:

```
+-------+----+----+----+
| State | 0  | 1  | Ɛ  |
+-------+----+----+----+
| q0    | q1 | -  | q1 |
| q1    |  - | q2 |  - |
| q2*   | q2 | q2 |  - |
+-------+----+----+----+
```

Since I have epsilon as a possible input, I'm a bit confused. What would the resulting DFA look like?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Probably the easiest approach is to work out the language accepted by the NFA. The $\epsilon$ transition simply means that it can progress from the initial state to $q_1$ without reading a character, so in effect it can start either at $q_0$ or at $q_1$. Can you now write down a regular expression for the language? There’s a further hint in the spoiler box.

> Either the NFA reads a $0$ and moves to $q_1$, or it moves to $q_1$ without reading a character. What must it read then in order for the input to be accepted?